# Is there a minimum device name length for BLE 4.0 advertising local name complete?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

For BLE advertising type LOCAL_NAME_COMPLETE, is there a minimum length requirement?

I could not find any length specification in the spec (other than it needs to fit in the advertising packet of 31 bytes minus anything else already in the advertisement packet), but am running into an issue where it may seem that there is.  I wanted to confirm here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [BLUETOOTH SPECIFICATION Version 4.0](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737) [Vol 3] section 12.1:

***...The Device Name characteristic value shall be 0 to 248 octets in length. A
device shall have only one instance of the Device Name characteristic.***

But since the AD packet is limited to 31 bytes then I guess that if it's too big then one should broadcast the shortened name instead of full name (different AD types)

So it seems like there is no limitations on a minimum size. Hope it helped.